# Gurobi uses 1 core on supercomputer node with 64 cores

Tags: gurobi

I have installed Gurobi 9.1.1 on a supercomputer node with 64 Xeon processors. For the installation I used conda.

I access this node via ssh. When running "htop" I see that the process uses 1 core at 100% and very rare times (lets say 1% of the total time) it uses 1 or 2 extra cores for only a few seconds.

In fact, my laptop with Intel i5 runs the same process using all the cores and is 10 times faster than the "supercomputer".

I have asked the admin of the server if this situation may be the result of a configuration in the server. I am waiting for her answer.

I have already added m.setParams("Threads", 64). But, there is no change.

What could be the reason for this situation?

Comment: What parameters/configuration are you running? What version of gurobi etc. Some detail would help...

Comment: Just to be sure: This problem occurs in the branch-and-bound tree exploration phase? Do you use callbacks?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to your Python script:

```
m.setParam('Threads', 64)
```

In which m is your gurobipy model defined as follow:

```
import gurobipy as gb
m = gb.Model('NewModel')
```

Comment: I have tried with your suggestion with no success. I edited the question.

Comment: Let's wait for the admin's reply. If it is not the configurations of the supercomputer, you need to try contacting Gurobi to check if your license is compatible with multi-processing. Although AFAIK Gurobi uses the maximum available number of cores during the solving process.